# XML Error - Not Well Formed

Tags: xml

I don't understand why I keep getting this error message:

Multiple annotations found at this line:

> - The markup in the document following the root element must be well-    formed.
> - error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element

The error is found below at the beginning of:

```
LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="30"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:weightSum="100">
<ScrollView android:layout_weight="30" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="30"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<AnalogClock
android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Feed it to xmllint or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_weight="40"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"/>

 <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

you have an extra `/` at the opening tag of LinearLayout

There is one in the next `LinearLayout` group too